# log file to sql when a new line is inserted

Tags: linux, bash

I have some lines in a log that I need to insert into a db.
I do this in a bash script using a variable $line.

When I do `INSERT INTO TABLE TBL_LOG(LOG_LINE) VALUES ($line)` if $line contains any special characters that needs to be escaped, the sql insert will fail. How can I escape all the special characters in $line by using the variable inside the sql insert ?

Comment: I didn't know bash had a database interface.  Can you add the script to your question?

Comment: Escaping will depend on the SQL dialect and the database you use... so you should at least mention this. Generic command-line substitution tools can also be used for custom escapes. Some database command line tools also have mechanisms to escape data, but since you didn't tell us which one you use ...